# Beginner issues with NASM: converting from string to number, and output to the console

Tags: nasm

I am just starting to learn NASM, and I am doing a first program involving a matrix in a text file. The file contains an N*N matrix, where the first line contains N, and the other lines each contain one row of the matrix. To start along my way in completing my larger task, i borrowed some code that reads a file line by line and outputs each line to the console.

I intend to read in the first line, convert it from string to integer, move that to a register i will use as a counter, then print out that many lines of the array. I figure even if N=7 and i fiddle with the top line of the file to say 3, if i get 3 lines printed then it works! However, this didn't work. I got it to print out always one line, suggesting that the number i read in and converted to int wasn't converted properly. I tried to output this number after conversion, but attempting to do so causes a seg fault, to my suprise!

Here is my code for NASM under Linux:

```
; this program demonstrates how to open files for reading
; It reads a text file line by line and displays it on the screen

extern fopen
extern fgets
extern fclose
extern printf
extern exit

global main

segment .data
readmode: db "r",0
filename: db "hw6_1.dat",0 ; filename to open
error1:   db "Cannot open file",10,0
format_1: db "%d",0

segment .bss
buflen:   equ 256         ; buffer length
buffer:   resd buflen     ; input buffer

segment .text
main: pusha
; OPENING FILE FOR READING  
push readmode       ; 1- push pointer to openmode   
push filename       ; 2- push pointer to filename
call fopen          ; fopen retuns a filehandle in eax
add esp, 8          ;   or 0 if it cannot open the file
cmp eax, 0          
jnz .L1             
push error1         ; report an error and exit
call printf
add esp, 4
jmp .L4

; READING FROM FILE     
.L1:  mov ebx, eax        ; save filepointer of opened file in ebx

; Get first line and pass to ecx
push ebx
push dword buflen
push buffer
call fgets
add esp, 12
cmp eax, 0
je .L3

;convert string -> numeric
push buffer
call parseInt
mov ecx, eax

.L2:  
;debug
push ecx
push format_1
call printf
add esp, 8

push ebx            ; 1- push filehandle for fgets
push dword buflen   ; 2- push max number of read chars
push buffer         ; 3- push pointer to text buffer
call fgets          ; get a line of text        
add esp, 12         ; clean up the stack
cmp eax, 0          ; eax=0 in case of error or EOF
je .L3
push buffer         ; output the read string
call printf
add esp, 4          ; clean up the stack
dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
jg .L2

;CLOSING FILE  
.L3:  push ebx            ; push filehandle 
call fclose         ; close file
add esp, 4          ; clean up stack

.L4:  popa
call exit

parseInt:   
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push ebx
push esi
mov esi, [ebp+8]        ; esi points to the string

xor eax, eax            ; clear the accumulator
.I1   cmp byte [esi], 0       ; end of string?
je .I2
mov ebx, 10
mul ebx                 ; eax *= 10
xor ebx, ebx
mov bl, [esi]           ; bl = character
sub bl, 48              ; ASCII conversion
add eax, ebx
inc esi
jmp .I1

.I2:   pop esi
pop ebx
pop ebp
ret 4
```

A sample data file is shown below, this is the one i was using:

```
4
2 45 16 22
17 21 67 29
45 67 97 35
68 34 90 72
```

I really dont understand how this is not working. The code to convert to integer was borrowed from WORKING programs, as is the code for output that i used to debug.

Comment: If you're just printing data and not using any formatting features of `printf`, then use `puts` instead. (Note that `puts` automatically appends a newline. If you don't want that, use `fputs` but be aware of the extra `FILE*` parameter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why are you calling `printf` with only one parameter?  The proto for `printf` is:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Second, your program works almost fine, you are just not exiting the program correctly!!  You are linking to the c library and it adds startup code, you need to call `exit` instead of `ret`.  Actually, just a `ret` is not the correct way to exit any program in Linux or Windows.

Your exit code should be:

```
.L4:  
    popa
    call    exit
```

and add `extern exit` to your list of externs.

Your `parseint` seems to return an incorrect number

*** EDIT ***

---

Since you are still having problems with `parseint`, from the `fgets` docs at the c++ site, you are not reading the whole thing:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and **included** in the string copied to
>   str.

So, what is happening is you are telling `fgets` to read in `dword buflen` number of bytes, which it will or it will stop reading when a `newline` is found and adds that to the buffer.

This:

```
; Get first line and pass to ecx
push ebx
push dword buflen
push buffer
call fgets
add esp, 12
```

should be:

```
; Get first line and pass to ecx
push ebx
push 1     ; <----- you only want to read 1 byte!
push buffer
call fgets
add esp, 12
```

Comment: I think i see the error with the parseInt. It needs to be a null terminated string, but the dat file has just the number as a string with no null termination. I am required not to give the text file a different style of format. This means i have to modify the push of the buffer to add a 0 terminator or something. I will work on that now.

Comment: I'm afraid i seem to be wrong. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ , "A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str." ... This means there IS a terminating character and the algorithm i borrowed for parsing a string to an int is just wrong, even though i can see nothing wrong with it! Also, since i am now using printf properly, i know that parseInt is returning a number around 250 depending on the number read in (much lower, like 3 or 4). Yet this number is positive, so why do i not get the "jg L2" condition to trigger?

Comment: Code has been updated to match current. parseInt still not working, as stated above.

Comment: Edited answer to include the fix

Comment: i was wondering about the newline recently actually, this confirms it. Thankfully, for this task the number on the first line is always less than 10. Therefore, your solution will work. Thank you!